# Understanding android values/dimens

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view

So I put the following in **values/dimens** & **values/dimens-mdpi**

```
<dimen name="rv_height">220dp</dimen>
<dimen name="rv_width">280dp</dimen>
```

and the following in **values-xxhdpi/dimens**

```
<dimen name="rv_height">260dp</dimen>
<dimen name="rv_width">320dp</dimen>
```

My question is, when I run this on **480 x 800 hdpi** API 17 emulator, why does it load dimens values from **xxhdpi** folder and not the regular **dimen** or **dimens-mdpi** folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

> To simplify the way that you design your user interfaces for multiple
>   screens, Android divides the range of actual screen sizes and
>   densities into:
>
> ldpi (low) ~120dpi
>
> mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
>
> hdpi (high) ~240dpi
>
> xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
>
> **xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi**
>
> xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

**Edit:**

I will try to explain it to you:

A device of 480 px on hdpi has a 320 dp because as from docs, "on a 240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels". means 400 px /1.5 = 320 dp.

Now, you have **values/dimens** & **values/dimens-mdpi** &&  **values-xxhdpi/dimens**

and again according to docs

> However, when the system is looking for a density-specific resource
>   and does not find it in the density-specific directory, it won't
>   always use the default resources. The system may instead use one of
>   the other density-specific resources in order to provide better
>   results when scaling. For example, when looking for a low-density
>   resource and it is not available, the system prefers to scale-down the
>   high-density version of the resource, because the system can easily
>   scale a high-density resource down to low-density by a factor of 0.5,
>   with fewer artifacts, compared to scaling a medium-density resource by
>   a factor of 0.75.

Conclusion: it's not grantee that the default directory will be always used in case of missing res-directory. And in your case it has scaled the higher-density resource down to low-density.

I hope it is clear now.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: actually I did, you are running a device of 480 dpi screen density and you created the folder `values-xxhdpi/dimens` which means your app will use the values exists in this folder!

Comment: That's the resolution not the dpi, the dpi is hdpi

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, BTW, may I ask for your source.

Comment: The official Android developer docs ! I have included the link first thing [in the beginning of the answer]

Comment: You're welcome but please for this answer or any other one you may find useful, consider accepting it for other people who may come through your questions. Thanks